# Restricting a non-constant map to an ample divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ And $Y$ be smooth projective irreducible varieties over the complex numbers. Let $f:X \to Y$ be a non-constant morphism.

Assume that the dimension of $X$ is at least two.

> **Question.** Let $D\subset X$ be an ample divisor. Is the restriction $f|_D : D\to X$ still non-constant?

This is false when $f$ is only assumed to be a rational map (and $D$ is not contained in the locus of indeterminacy of $f$).

Also, if $f$ is finite, then the answer is positive. Finally, if $f$ has at least two positive-dimensional fibres, the answer is also positive.

Comment: @Pop. Why is this? I agree that if $D$ is contracted by $f$ then $f$ has only one fibre of dimension $>0$ (containing $D$) but I do not see what else one can say a priori.

Comment: @DamianRössler: I claimed a bit more than my proof shows. I wrote an answer below to elaborate on what I had in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me expand my comment into an answer. I weaken my previous claim a bit to say that if $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$ is any nonconstant morphism and $D$ is an effective ample divisor on $X$, then $f(D)$ cannot be a point.

Suppose $X$ has dimension at least 2, $D$ is an effective ample divisor on $X$, and $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$ is a nonconstant morphism that contracts $D$ to a point. Replacing $Y$ with $f(X)$ if necessary, we can assume $f$ is surjective.

If $Y$ has dimension at least 2, choose a curve $C_Y \subset Y$ which does not pass through the point $f(D)$. Then by taking appropriate hyperplane sections of $f^{-1}(C_Y)$ one can find a curve $C \subset X$ which maps onto $C_Y$. Since $f(D)$ is disjoint from $C_Y$, the divisor $D$ is disjoint from $C$. But this contradicts ampleness of $D$.

(The same argument shows that $f(D)$ cannot have codimension $\geq 2$ in $Y$.)

If $Y$ has dimension 1, then all fibres of $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$ are divisors, and $D$ is contained in a single fibre of $f$. Choose $C$ to be any curve contained in a different fibre. Then $D$ is disjoint from $C$, again a contradiction.

Comment: Quite right! That settles it. More concisely: the reduced inverse image by $f$ over any closed subvariety of $f(X)$ not containing $f(D)$ has degree $0$ with resp. to ${\cal O}(D)$, which is not possible. This also works if $D$ is not effective.

Comment: @DamianRössler: that's a nice reformulation, thanks.

Comment: @Pop I think there are a few minor inaccuracies. 1) $f:X\to Y$ should not be any morphism, but non-constant. Also, $X$ and $Y$ should be projective (I guess this is implicit because the OP assumes this). 2) The inverse image $f^{-1}(C_Y)$ could be empty. However, you can reduce to the case that $f$ is surjective by replacing $Y$ with $Im(f)$. 3)  In the last paragraph "are curves" should be "are positive-dimensional", right?

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar: sure, all correct, let me fix.

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer, too long to be a comment.

Let me give a family of examples where $D$ can be found (every effective divisor $D$ works, actually).

Take any smooth, projective variety $X$ admitting a finite endomorphim $f \colon X \to X$ of degree $\geq 2$, and let $f_i \colon X \to X$ be the composition of $f$ with itself $i$ times.

Since $f$ is finite, the same holds for $f_i$ and so $f_i$ does not contract any subvariety of positive dimension. In particular, the restriction of $f_i$ to every (ample) divisor is non-constant for all $i \geq 1$.

**Examples:**

- $X$= Abelian variety, $f \colon X \to X$ is the multiplication by $2$;
- $X=\mathbb{P}^n$, $f \colon X \to X$ is given by $[x_0: \ldots :x_n] \mapsto [x_0^2: \ldots: x_n^2]$.

Comment: I think the question of the OP is for any $X$ and $Y$ and non-constant morphisms $f_i$ (it does not ask for some specific example).

Comment: Well, maybe you are right. I edited the answer.

Comment: That is not what I mean.. in the the OP's question, $X$ and the $f_i$ are already fixed. It is $D$ and the subsequence of the $f_i$ that should be found. If you want to fix $X$ and the $f_i$ then you have to find a counterexample.

Comment: Yes, I understand. My partial answer should be read just as "For some particular choice of $X$, $Y$ and the $f_i$, the divisor $D$ can be found". I do not know in general. I agree that this is not a complete answer, but it is better than nothing.

Comment: On the other hand, since the OP provided neither background nor motivation, it is difficult to know how much information they have about the problem.

Comment: Yes I agree that it would be good to have more info!

Comment: Thank you for all this. I have edited my question. Your comments made me understand what my "real" question really is.